Install drake==1.32.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
my ubuntu is 20.04, with python=3.11.9.
I tried to install drake==1.32.0 using pip, but it shows error like this:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement drake==1.32.0 (from versions: 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.23.0, 1.24.0, 1.25.0, 1.26.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for drake==1.32.0`

Can you tell me what is the reason? Is it because drake does not release the latest version for Ubuntu 20.04?
I tried python==3.12 and also different pip versions. All of them did not help.

That's correct. We currently support 22.04 and 24.04.  https://drake.mit.edu/installation.html

Details about older versions are here:
https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/end_of_support.html
